# iPhone: Visual Studio for Mac - Automatic signing failed: There are no current devices on this team matching the provided device IDs

Tags: iphone, app-store, sign, visual-studio-mac

I am developing an iPhone App on a MacBook Pro, using Visual Studio Community for Mac latest version.

I want to publish an app to App Store and currently at the stage of doing an Automatic Signing.

And this end with the following error message:

> Automatic signing failed: There are no current devices on this team matching the provided device IDs.

I don't have a physical real iPhone. All I use is the iPhone Simulator.
Is it a must to use a real iPhone to sign the App and submit to App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you or the team member of the Apple Developer Account must have real iPhone. and yes, to publish the app to App Store, you need a real physical iPhone.

Comment: I do have an iphone, don't have a mac. using codemagic. what shold i do ?

Comment: @user3156040 yupe, sorry that, you need a real mac too :) you don't need a new mac, you can buy a cheap used old mac. that would fine too. not too old, but old enough to support latest MacOS. note that xcode does not run on old (very old) version of MacOS. a little bit old, but not too old :)